# Php Function not working in PDO

Tags: php, function, pdo

I have made a function in old mysql and now want to transfer it to PDO, but its not working.  Here is my new code:

```
global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT SUM(score), SUM(score_from) FROM school_test_report, school_students 
    WHERE (school_test_report.student_id = school_students.student_id 
    and school_test_report.class=school_students.class) 
    and school_test_report.student_id = '$student_id' and  school_test_report.subject = '$subject'
    and school_test_report.test_date >= '$thisarch'
                                ")
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $STH;
```

and it outputs:

```
$student_id = test_score_month($name, 'English');
echo $student_id['score'].'/'.$student_id['score_from'];
```

Here is old code which is working:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(score), SUM(score_from) FROM school_test_report, school_students 
    WHERE (school_test_report.student_id = school_students.student_id 
    and school_test_report.class=school_students.class) 
    and school_test_report.student_id = '$student_id' and  school_test_report.subject = '$subject'
    and school_test_report.test_date >= '$thisarch'
                                ")
    or die(mysql_error());  
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
 return $row;
```

and it outputs:

```
$student_id = test_score_month($name, 'English');
echo $student_id['score'].'/'.$student_id['score_from'];
```

Comment: Define "not working". `PDO::query` returns a `PDOStatement`, not the result array. You need to check if it's really a `PDOStatement` (it could also be FALSE if there was an error in the query), and use one of the fetch functions, for example, [`$STH->fetch()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) to get the result array.

Comment: Just because you're using PDO doesn't make you immune to SQL injection attacks. You're not using prepared statements, not using placeholders, and directly inserting external data into a query string. Enjoy having your database pwn3d.

Comment: The point of using PDO is prepared querys feature, if your not going to use it your script is just as vulnerable to sql injection as the mysql_* functions

Comment: as i told u guys i am new to PDO so please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres is an example, wrap all your functions todo with your querys related to your users in a model class and then call each method to return your result ect, see how the function/method uses placeholders `:student_id` then bindParam's the values to thos placeholders, it is just an example but will help you understand abit more.

```
<?php 
class user_model{

    private $db;

    function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pass){
        $this->dbhost = $host;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->dbuser = $user;
        $this->dbpass = $pass;
    }

    private function connect(){
        if (!$this->db instanceof PDO){
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$this->dbname.';host='.$this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }

    function user_test_score($student_id,$subject,$thisarch){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT SUM(score) as score, SUM(score_from) FROM school_test_report, school_students
                WHERE (school_test_report.student_id = school_students.student_id 
                AND school_test_report.class=school_students.class) 
                AND school_test_report.student_id = :student_id and  school_test_report.subject = :subject
                AND school_test_report.test_date >= :thisarch";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':thisarch', $thisarch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}


$usermodel = new user_model('localhost','YOURDB','username','password');

$student_id = $usermodel->user_test_score($name,'English',your_test_date_format);

print_r($student_id);
?>
```